# Как сохранить пробелы в SVG тексте

Tags: javascript, svg

Необходимо в текстовый элемент вставлять новое значение. Значение может быть от `0.0` до `100.0`. т.е. максимальное количество символов в строке может быть `5`. Есть код, который добавляет нужное количество пробелов справа и слева, если длина текста меньше `5`.

Проблема в том, что если в строке имеются подстроки из пробелов (`> 1`), то они заменяются на один пробел. Нашел решение: заменить пробелы на символ `'\u00A0'`. Это работает для строк вида `1.0` и `22.4`, но если в строке будут все `5` знаков, т.е. это строка `100.0`, текст смещается.

Разное поведение можно увидеть, если изменять в моем коде значение переменной `new_value`.

Как сделать, чтобы текст всегда имел один формат: `Ia:` `n-пробелов, если нужно` `значение` `m-пробелов, если нужно` `A`.

```js
new_value = '5.0';  // обязательно один символ после точки
let max_length = 5;

const len = new_value.length;
new_value = new_value.padStart(len + Math.floor((max_length - len) / 2), ' ');
new_value = new_value.padEnd(max_length, ' ');

new_value = `Ia: ${new_value} A`;

new_value = new_value.replace(' ', '\u00A0');

text = document.querySelector('text');
text.innerHTML = new_value;
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 128 128">
  <rect width="384" height="384" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="none" id="background"/>
  <g id="root" transform="translate(0,0)">
    <g transform="translate(64,20)">
      <rect x="-56.5" y="-8.5" width="113" height="17" fill="#FFFF00" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0" opacity="1.0"/>
      <text transform="translate(0,4.861111111111111)" fill="#000000" font-family="Consolas" font-size="14pt" text-anchor="middle">Ia: 0.0 &#1040;</text>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: а зачем пробелы?

Comment: Чтобы преамбула (Ia:) и завершение (А) всегда были по краям, а текст ровно по центру (ну ровно будет не всегда, т.к. сначала пробел добавляется cправа, потом слева, аналог python `str.center()`). Т.к. шрифт моноширинный, решил выравнивать пробелами.

Comment: поапробуйте text-anchor=“middle”

Comment: Нет, он выравнивает весь текст. Тогда `Ia: 5.0 A` и `Ia: 15.0 A` будут различаться по оформлению в том смысле, что расстояние `Ia:` и `A` от границы будет разное. Я решил это обойти так: к строке `Ia: 5.0 A` добавить после 5.0 пробел, получить `Ia: 5.0  A`, тогда для моноширинного текста общий размер текста сохраняется. В общем суть в том, что мне нужно всегда иметь фиксированное количество символов в строке.

Comment: может это 3 разных текста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как метод `str.replace` заменяет только первое вхождение подстроки (в моем случае), возникала проблема, которая описана в вопросе. Замена всех вхождений `_` (space) на `\u00A0` решает проблему.

Необходимо изменить код

```
new_value = new_value.replace(' ', '\u00A0');
```

на

```
new_value = new_value.replace(/ /g, '\u00A0');
```